# Spring-boot start so slow when integrate with rabbitmq SimpleMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmq with spring-boot ,and here is my consumer config:

```
@Bean(value = "distributionMqConnectionFactory")
public ConnectionFactory distributionMqConnectionFactory(){
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new CachingConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setAddresses(distributionMqServerAddress);
    connectionFactory.setVirtualHost(distributionMqServerVirtualHost);
    connectionFactory.setUsername(distributionMqServerUserName);
    connectionFactory.setPassword(distributionMqServerPassword);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean(value = "distributionMessageListenerContainer")
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer distributionMessageListenerContainer(@Qualifier("distributionMqConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                                           @Qualifier("distributionMqConsumer") DistributionMqConsumer mqConsumer, @Qualifier("distributionConsumerQueue") Queue queue) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.setQueues(queue);
    container.setRabbitAdmin(distributionRabbitAdmin());
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);
    container.setAutoStartup(false);
    if (distributionMqConsumerEnable) {
        container.setMessageListener(mqConsumer);
        container.start();
    }
    return container;
}
```

if i set `distributionMqConsumerEnable=true` and start application, it starts very slow, but when set `distributionMqConsumerEnable=false`, it becomes normal, after look at the console output, i found it block in

```
[INFO] [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory:359] Created new connection: SimpleConnection@21561d6 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 51131]
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem exist in `container.start();`, as we can see the in source code:

```
/**
 * Retrieve the fatal startup exception if this processor completely failed to locate the broker resources it
 * needed. Blocks up to 60 seconds waiting for an exception to occur
 * (but should always return promptly in normal circumstances).
 * No longer fatal if the processor does not start up in 60 seconds.
 * @return a startup exception if there was one
 * @throws TimeoutException if the consumer hasn't started
 * @throws InterruptedException if the consumer startup is interrupted
 */
private FatalListenerStartupException getStartupException() throws TimeoutException, InterruptedException {
    this.start.await(60000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS); //NOSONAR - ignore return value
    return this.startupException;
}
```

so i think the mq bean initialized, and it wait from something else, after read:
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/amqp/747305-60-seconds-delay-when-calling-start-on-simplemessagelistenercontainer, i decide to do `container.start()` after all spring bean in my application are ready, and it works. Here is my solution:

```
@Component
public class TeddySmartLifeCycleConfig implements SmartLifecycle{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("distributionMessageListenerContainer")
    private SimpleMessageListenerContainer distributionContainer;
    //start mq containter
    private void startMqConsumer(){
        distributionContainer.start();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isAutoStartup() {
        return true; //return true so start() method will be called
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(Runnable callback) {

    }
    //this will called when all beans are ready
    @Override
    public void start() {
        startMqConsumer();
    }
```

you can google for more about `SmartLifecycle`